# Sorting a range of columns case-wise and applying that sort order to another range of columns

Tags: r, sorting

In R I've got a data frame containing the indices of images (i1,i2,i3) that were presented in a randomized order and as well a rating for each image (a1,a2,a3):

[image]

Now I would like to add new variables that represent the indices of the presented images in ascending order (i1_s,i2_s,i3_s). This re-ordering has to be applied to the corresponding answers as well (a1_s,a2_s,a3_s). So the final data frame should look like this:

[image]

How can I do this task in R?
I think this should be a pretty common task that has to be done a lot in randomized study designs, but I couldn't find how-tos or tutorials. The problem is, I don't know the proper technical terms for this kind of operation.

*Note: Since in the actual study there are hundreds of image- and answer-variables, a generic approach that operates on patterns of variable names is highly appreciated!*

EDIT: added code for above sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("1", "2", "3"),
  i1 = c(78, 19, 4),
  i2 = c(19, 4, 78),
  i3 = c(4, 78, 19),
  a1 = c("B", "D", "M"),
  a2 = c("A", "H", "A"),
  a3 = c("D", "A", "E"),
  i1_s = c(NA,NA,NA),
  i2_s = c(NA,NA,NA),
  i3_s = c(NA,NA,NA),
  a1_s = c(NA,NA,NA),
  a2_s = c(NA,NA,NA),
  a3_s = c(NA,NA,NA)
)
```

Comment: Hi! Can you use `dput` to share your (example) data set?

Comment: I don't know how to use `dput` for that, but I added code for sample data at the end of my question. Hope this is sufficient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another `tidyverse` approach. You can provide a `names_pattern` when putting your data into long form. After sorting values with `arrange` for each `ID`, you can `pivot_wider` to put back into wide form if desired.

**Edit**: As the `i1_s`, `i2_s`, etc. columns ending in "_s" are automatically generated from the script, you do not need to create "empty" columns ahead of time. For this example, I just removed them.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(-(i1_s:a3_s)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID, 
               names_to = c(".value", "number"), 
               names_pattern = "(\\w+)(\\d+)") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(i) %>%
  mutate(number = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, 
              names_from = number, 
              names_glue = "{.name}_s", 
              values_from = c(-ID, -number), 
              names_sep = "")
```

**Output**

```
  ID     i1_s  i2_s  i3_s a1_s  a2_s  a3_s 
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1         4    19    78 D     A     B    
2 2         4    19    78 H     D     A    
3 3         4    19    78 M     E     A
```

Comment: Your answer produces correkt entries, but new variable names with NAs are gererated: i4_s, i5_s, i6_s and a4_s, a5_s, a6_s. How can I avoid that?

Comment: @Madamadam See my edited answer. As the `i1_s`, `i2_s`, etc. columns ending in "_s" are automatically generated from the script, you do not need to create "empty" columns ahead of time. For this example, I just removed them. Does that help?

Comment: that's it! Thank you.

Comment: One last question: in my original dataset, I have another column XY, which keeps some information but doesn't play a role in re-arranging/sorting. If I add `cols = c(-ID, -XY)` to your code and run it, the `pivot_longer` looks good, but calling `pivot_wider` introduces the colmuns XY1_s, XY2_s, and XY3_s. What do I have to do, to convert the long format successfully back to wide format, only having one simple XY column?

Comment: I think you could try `pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, XY),...values_from = c(-ID, -number, -XY),...` ... just add `XY` in those two places and see if that works...

Answer (score 1):

Curious to see how others do this but here's one solution.

```
df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(across(-ID, as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
  mutate(
    num = substring(name,2),
    name = substring(name,1,1)
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    i = as.numeric(i)
  ) %>%
  arrange(ID, i) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    rank1 = row_number()
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    i = as.character(i)
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(i,a)) %>%
  mutate(
    name = paste0(name, rank1, '_s')
  ) %>%
  select(-num, -rank1) %>%
  arrange(ID, name) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('i'), as.numeric))
```

---

Output:

```
     ID a1_s  a2_s  a3_s   i1_s  i2_s  i3_s
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 D     A     B         4    19    78
2     2 H     D     A         4    19    78
3     3 M     E     A         4    19    78
```

---

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, i1 = c(78L, 19L, 4L), i2 = c(19L, 4L, 
78L), i3 = c(4L, 78L, 19L), a1 = c("B", "D", "M"), a2 = c("A", 
"H", "A"), a3 = c("D", "A", "E")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you add some comments to your code so it's comperhensible for non-savvy users? And: to use your code, it's necessary to install `tidyverse`, isn't it?